# v-autocomplete not showing all the item in selection list from list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, frontend, vuetify.js

I am sending array which has value from 1-100 on v-autocomplete item props. But on scrollbar only number till 40-50 shows up.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-autocomplete
        label="Autocomplete"
        :items="CountList"
        variant="outlined"
      >
        <template #item="{ item }">
          <v-list-item>{{ item.raw }}</v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-autocomplete>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, inject } from 'vue'
  const CountList = ref([])
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    CountList.value.push(i)
  }
</script>
```

In dwopdown list number till 100 should showup. But when I use <template #item> complete number till 100 doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look in vuetify docs and in the item slot section of v-autocomplete it says:
"*Define a custom item appearance. The root element of this slot must be a v-list-item with v-bind="props" applied. props includes everything required for the default select list behaviour - including title, value, click handlers, virtual scrolling, and anything else that has been added with item-props.*"

So i guess you need to bind props to your slot. This shows all the items up to 100.

```
<template #item="{ props, item }">
  <v-list-item v-bind="props" :title="item.raw"/>
</template>
```

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVUctuwjAQ/JWVewAEGOjjUAqVUK/9A8LBBKO6MrZlr9NDlH/v2iEhOdk7M7s7Hh9rFny5OjjHqyjZlu1Q3pwWKD8LA7CrlsK5fM1FaQ0KZaS/Q60ioi0tdUmUHQygxVnqfcEOQ5Y9+K2iTYEEXzYa/FYBh2wlvBIGibYRNW28PNh+N23v3MJTGkfyGpy3Liwg1dAUbKDObjVtWmayWp6VuVBP7igYbFGhlgQkmnvxR9hquG01CqeFxu/voiJ4nFUW5ihHU6gMpVcOIUiMbdLq5qxHqMHLK73D/MoSoYGrtzeY0C9NkoimB4Q+O9gn9fR4miXyaj1MyQ4owjcfdOzoXK/pNp/PoG5N9s28EjpK7mL4mao8oEk2W2NkiTUL9sJf+fOGpcsbf2enf5v6sWk=)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item-title property as follows:

```
<v-autocomplete
  label="Autocomplete"
  :items="CountList"
  variant="outlined"
  :item-title="item => item"
>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).