Vuetify v-select item slot rendering only max 57 items
While integrating a custom v-select component, I discovered the following behavior:
const items = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 200; index++) {
  items.push(index);


<v-select label="Select" :items="items" />

Renders as expected all 200 items in the Select dropdown

But when using a slot instead:
const items = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 200; index++) {
  items.push(index);

<v-select label="Select" :items="items">
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <span>{{ item.title }}&nbsp;</span>
  </template>
</v-select>

It renders only the first 57 items...

This is just a boiled down example to the very issue.
Vue version 3.4.21
Vuetify version 3.5.14
Did I miss something?
Is this some kind of permformance optimization?
It is very annoying that I cannot visualize all entries....

From vuetify docs: 'The root element of this slot must be a v-list-item with v-bind="props" applied.'

Isn't this a CSS issue? Right side being cropped?

Thanks a lot @fOURP ! It solved my issue. But honestly, I didn't find that info in the current documentation.
I saw you answered already an almost similar question for autocomplete. Found it after your answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78186377/v-autocomplete-not-showing-all-the-item-in-selection-list-from-list

Here is what is written in the vuetify documentation about the item slot:

Define a custom item appearance. The root element of this slot must be a v-list-item with v-bind="props" applied. props includes everything required for the default select list behaviour - including title, value, click handlers, virtual scrolling, and anything else that has been added with
item-props.
Source: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-item

I hope the code below will clarify everything.
<template>
  <v-select label="Select" :items="items">
    <template v-slot:item="{ props }">
      <v-list-item v-bind="props" />
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>
<script setup>
  const items = []
  for (let index = 0; index < 200; index++) {
   items.push(index)
  }
</script>

